# Unable to retrieve DBMS_ALERT for a C# application

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to use `DBMS_ALERT` to provide feedback to a C# application from an Oracle 11g database.  In testing the stored procedures in the oracle tool TOAD, I am unable to retrieve any alerts.

I'll show the stored procedures that I have written.

My reason for doing this is to provide feedback to a progress bar on a winform.

Am I misapplying the use of `DBMS_ALERT`?  I am new to Oracle, my background is with MSSQL server.

Here is my stored procedure to generate an alert:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HOWMET.DB_ALERT  (iMsg VARCHAR2) AS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    DBMS_ALERT.SIGNAL('ALERT', iMsg);
    COMMIT;
  END DB_ALERT;
```

Here is my stored procedure to read an alert:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HOWMET.GET_DB_ALERT_MSG(oMsg    OUT VARCHAR2,
                                                oStatus OUT INTEGER)
AS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER('ALERT');
    DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE('ALERT', oMsg, oStatus,5);
    DBMS_ALERT.REMOVE('ALERT');
END;
```

Here is the main stored procedure that I am using to test the use of `DBMS_ALERT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HOWMET.GETDATAWITHALERTS(EmployeeCur           OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                 EmployeeGridFormatCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN

DB_ALERT('Starting Point 1');  <- calling an external sproc to signal the alert
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(5);  

OPEN EmployeeCur FOR
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
       FIRST_NAME,
       LAST_NAME,
       EMAIL,
       HIRE_DATE,
       DEPARTMENT_ID,
       CAST(SALARY AS INT) AS "SALARY"
  FROM HR.EMPLOYEES;

DB_ALERT('Mid Point 2'); <- calling an external sproc to signal the alert
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(5);

OPEN EmployeeGridFormatCur FOR
SELECT 'Employee ID|Hidden' AS "Employee_ID",
       'First Name' AS "First_Name",
       'Last Name|Width:90' AS "Last_Name",
       'Email|Width:80' AS "Email",
       'Hire Date|Width:80' AS "Hire_Date",
       'Dept Id|Width:65' AS "DEPARTMENT_ID",
       'Salary|Right|Fill|FMT:#`##0.00' AS "Salary"
  FROM DUAL;

DB_ALERT('End 3'); <- calling an external sproc to signal the alert
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(5);

END GETDATAWITHALERTS;
```

Here's the C# code in where I am experiencing an error.  I keep getting error -> "PL/SQL: numeric or value error".

```
string Message = "";
int Status = -1;
bool bStatus;
try
{
  using (OracleConnection oCnn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
  using (OracleDataAdapter oDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
  using (OracleCommand dbmsAlert = new OracleCommand("GET_DB_ALERT_MSG", oCnn))
  {
     dbmsAlert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // create output parameters
     dbmsAlert.Parameters.Add("oMsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1800, ParameterDirection.Output);
     dbmsAlert.Parameters.Add("oStatus", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
     dbmsAlert.Connection.Open();
     dbmsAlert.ExecuteNonQuery();

     bStatus = int.TryParse(dbmsAlert.Parameters["oStatus"].Value.ToString(), out Status);
     Message = dbmsAlert.Parameters["oMsg"].Value.ToString();

     if (Status == 0)  //0 = Alert Received, 1 = Timed out
     {
        if (Message != null && Message != String.Empty && Message != "null")
        {
           MessageBox.Show(Message, "Feedback");
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show(System.String.Format("No Message! Status:{0} Msg:{1}", Status, Message), "Feedback");
        }
     }
  }
}
catch
{
  throw;
  //raise an error
}
```

Comment: So what happens when you call HOWMET.GET_DB_ALERT_MSG just from straight sql*plus commandline?

Comment: I have been testing in a tool named dbforge studio for Oracle, I haven't tried sql*plus. Testing with the GUI tool, the procedure GET_DB_ALERT_MSG only works if I add a DBMS_Alert.register to the main stored procedure "GETDATAWITHALERTS" and remove the DBMS_Alert.register and DBMS_Alert.remove from stored procedure GET_DB_ALERT_MSG.  I am confused by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. It is related to my use of the add method of the OracleParameterCollection in the Oracle.DataAccess.Client namespace.  My use of fewer parameters for this method caused the wrong override to be implemented. In my original post, I had the following line for specifying the output parameter of the stored procedure retrieving the dbms alert.

```
dbmsAlert.Parameters.Add("oMsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1800, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

This is using the following override:

```
public OracleParameter Add(string name, OracleDbType dbType, int size, 
string srcColumn);
```

I should have written this instead:

```
dbmsAlert.Parameters.Add("oMsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1800, Message, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

This is using the desired override:

```
public OracleParameter Add(string name, OracleDbType dbType, int size, 
object val, ParameterDirection dir;
```

My C# application can now detect DBMS_ALERTs from Oracle.